# How to determine the sample size for a two sided $z$-test?

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, law-of-large-numbers, sampling-theory

Let $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}$ be an iid sample from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$
where $\sigma$ is known. We want to test a hypothesis 
$$
H_{0}:\mu = \mu_{0}
\quad \mbox{versus} \quad 
H_{1}: \mu \ne \mu_0
$$
Now, assume that the values of $\alpha$ (probability of Type I Error)
and $\beta$ (Probability of Type II Error) are fixed in advance.

Therefore, the problem now is to determine what should be the sample size to achieve the desired value of $\beta$?

Here is what I progressed:

The power function is given by
$$
w(\mu) 
=
1 + 
\Phi
\left(
k-z_{\alpha/2}
\right)
-
\Phi
\left(
k+z_{\alpha/2}
\right),
$$
where 
$$
k = \frac{\mu_0-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}.
$$
We also know that 
$$
w(\mu) = 1 - \beta(\mu),
$$
where $\beta(\mu)$ is the probability of making Type II error when the true parameter value is $\mu$.

Now, it is evident that in order to achieve the desired value of $\beta$, we need to set up the equation
$$
1-\beta = w(\mu),
$$
and solve this equation for $n$.

But I am not sure how to solve this equation for $n$.

I just found on one of the textbooks without any work that
the minimum sample size should be
$$
n \ge 
\left[
\frac{\sigma(z_{\beta} + z_{\alpha/2})}
{\mu_0-\mu}
\right]^2
$$
as an approximated solution.

But again how do we get this approximated solution?

Thank you!

Comment: You may see a solution here at this \herf{https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3377178/how-to-derive-the-sample-size-n-to-achieve-p-texttype-2-error-beta-fo}{link}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approximated solution can be derived as below.

\begin{align*}
& {\qquad}
1-\beta 
= 
w(\mu) \\  
& {\qquad}
= 
1 + 
\Phi
\left(
k-z_{\alpha/2}
\right)
-
\Phi
\left(
k+z_{\alpha/2}
\right) \\
& {\qquad} = 
P(Z \ge z_{\alpha/2}-|k|) + P(Z \ge z_{\alpha/2}+|k|) \\
\Rightarrow & {\qquad} 
1-\beta \approx P(Z \ge z_{\alpha/2}-|k|),
\quad \mbox{assuming} \quad P(Z \ge z_{\alpha/2}+|k|) \approx 0 \\
\iff & {\qquad} 
z_{1-\beta} \approx z_{\alpha/2}-|k| \\
\iff & {\quad}
-z_{\beta} \approx z_{\alpha/2}-|k| \\
\iff & {\quad} 
|k| \approx  z_{\alpha/2}+z_{\beta},
\end{align*}
this gives 
$$
n \approx
\left[
\frac{\sigma(z_{\beta} + z_{\alpha/2})}
{\mu_0-\mu}
\right]^2,
$$
as desired.